# how to use .data() to append 2 children to parent w/o counting an existing child?

Tags: d3.js

```
d3.select(this).selectAll("li")
   .data(function(d) {
      return [{"name": "tab1"},{"name": "tab2"}]
   })
   .enter()
   .append(function(d, i) {
      return document.createElement("li");
   })
   .html(function(d,i) {
      return "Test1";
   });
```

If there is already an "li" in "this", only one will be added ... how do I use .data() to add the 2 "li"s and keep the one that is already there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, when you write `selectAll("li")`, you are selecting the existent `li` and joining the data to them. You have to use another selection, for instance, `selectAll(".newLi")`.

```
d3.select(this).selectAll(".newList")
    .data(function(d) {
        return [{"name": "tab1"},{"name": "tab2"}]
    })
    .enter()
    .append(function(d, i) {
        return document.createElement("li");
    })
    .html(function(d,i) {
        return "Test1";
    });
```

In this fiddle, click on the existent `li` ("this" and "that") to append the new elements: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/8s2g77kf/

To finish, there is nothing wrong in using pure JS, but D3 makes your life easier... you can append simply using:

```
.append("li")
```

*PS: This has been asked so many times... not even a "duplicate", maybe a "multiplicate".*

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Oh, it happens all the time: people use `selectAll("rect")` for an SVG rectangle or `selectAll("p")`for an paragraph, and so on, and they end up selecting existent elements (in D3, the `selectAll` in an enter selection is just an placeholder, you should not select any existent element). Just this week we had 2 or 3 problems like this I believe, you can search using `d3` tag.